# regexp match anything before and after a word, if it exists

Tags: regex

I have sentences like these

```
word1 word2 abc word3 word4
word1 word2 word3 word4
```

And I want to get the matches:

1. everything before `abc`
2. `abc` or nothing
3. everything after `abc`

I need 3 different matches because $1 and $3 will be copied to the output as they are, while $2 should be modified. I expect $2 not always to be there, as well as $3).

My current solution is this one

```
(.+?(?=abc))(abc)?(.*)
```

This doesn't work if `abc` is not part of the sentence. How can I express "match everything until that word if it exists" with regex?

P.S. I am using JS (not sure if it's relevant)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(.*?)(?:(abc)(.*))?$
```

If the string can have line breaks, use

```
^([\w\W]*?)(?:(abc)([\w\W]*))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F6iGhe/2). In JS, `[\w\W]` can be replaced with `[^]` to match any chars including line break chars.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break  chars as few as possible
- `(?:(abc)(.*))?` - an optional greedy pattern matching one or zero times:

  - `(abc)` - Group 2: `abc`
  - `(.*)` - Group 3: any zero or more chars other than line break  chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

Since the first group pattern is non-greedy, it will keep expanding from the start of the string until the first occurrence of the optional non-capturing group pattern (if present) or end of string, and if there is `abc`, the second and third groups will be populated, else the whole string will land in Group 1.

Comment: The first one is definitely the solution I was looking for. Added `?:` to my regex knowledge base, thanks!

Comment: @Cray Copy/paste issue. Fixed.